# How to show certain rows only in serverside processing?

Tags: php, datatables

I would like to show only certain rows to logged in users where "column_name" = "some_value" in serverside-processing. Currently i use following code below.

```
$table = 'tablename';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
   array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
   array( 'db' => 'name', 'dt' => 1 ), // need to only select where name ="example"
   array( 'db' => 'views', 'dt' => 2 )
);
}
$sql_details = array(
   'user' => 'db_user',
   'pass' => 'db_pass',
   'db' => 'db_name',
   'host' => 'localhost:3306'
);
require( 'server-processing.php' );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can do this by using

```
  SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns , "column_name = 'some_value'"  )
```

instead of `simple` use `complex` and then add `"column_name = 'some_value'` extra inside the bracket.